React Native: TypeError 'Cannot read property length of undefined' triggered by setState in toggle function
I'm encountering an issue in my React Native application where the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" is triggered whenever I use a setState function inside a toggle function. Here’s my toggle function:
const toggleSwitchGarmin = () => {
    const newState = !isGarminSynchro;  

    if (newState) {
        setCurrentFit('Garmin');
        setIsFitSynchro(false);  
        setSyncState('isFitSynced', false); //  
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? deauthorizeGoogleFit() : deauthorizeAppleHealth();
         setModalEnabled(true);  
    } else {
        setModalEnabled(false);  
        setCurrentFit('None');  
    }

    setIsGarminSynchro(newState);
};

The only thing the function should do is change the states

when setState is called on a component, it re-renders the component and its children except memoized,
your'e getting this error because, your component has re-rendered and your'e probably trying to get the length of a value which either doesn't exists yet, or doesn't have the length property
fix:

check your component / child components for where your'e trying to check length & add optional chaining eg array?.length or string?.length etc
check that the variable exists before checking its length eg. Array.isArray(value) && value.length


That's the funny thing: in the component that executes the switch there is no object that is an array, only the switch is used to change the states.
